# How to addFieldToFilter a double number

Tags: magento-1.9

```
//$place_longitude = 106.63156128
//$place_latitude = 10.85593987
```

I have tried this way but still does not work

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('hihi_place/place')
                ->getCollection()
//                ->addFieldToFilter(
//                    array('longitude', 'latitude'),
//                    array(
//                        array('eq'=>doubleval($place_longitude)),
//                        array('eq'=>doubleval($place_latitude))
//                    )
//                );
                ->addFieldToFilter('latitude',$place_latitude)
                ->addFieldToFilter('longitude',$place_longitude);
```

If I use the word "like" it works fine, but I just wanted to get the exact value that I entered.
Thanks.

Comment: please check database field float or not?

Comment: @AmitBera longitude and latitude in database are float type.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following expression. It worked for us:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('hihi_place/place')
                ->getCollection();

$select = $collection->getSelect();
$select
    ->where('latitude =  ' . $place_latitude)
    ->where('longitude =  ' . $place_longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

Double type variable  is [deprecated from PHP 4.2.0](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64982).

you need use float type variable

So,please try:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('latitude',$place_latitude)
                ->addFieldToFilter('longitude', (float) $place_longitude)
            ->addFieldToFilter('longitude', (float)  $place_longitude);
```

Then use echo  `$collection->getSelect()->__toString();` for checking data is give right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do 
$collection->printLogQuery(true);
see the sql query and modify accordingly. :)